# How to restore the previous version of log file?

Tags: files, restore, text-editor

I run my program on my college server and have to provide a log file to update the results of the program.

Accidently I submitted a program without updating the name of the log file and hence the older version of the log file is no longer accessible to me. But the results are important for me and hence I want to restore the previous version of the log file.

Is there any way to do restoration?

Comment: Did you overwrite the file?  If so it's not recoverable.  Overwritten data can not be restored.

Comment: @Nmath I think the program overrode the old contents with new ones.

Comment: Then unfortunately you will not be able to recover it unless the software itself employs some kind of file history.